# What happens if I set both UILabel.text and UILabel.attributedText?

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, core-text, nsattributedstring

I have an attributed string which I am making out of HTML using `DTCoreText`, and I want to set it as the value of my UILabel. However, I want to check at a later point if the value of the string has changed, in comparison to the UILabel. Is it possible to set both the UILabel's `text` and `attributedText` properties? Will the `attributedText` simply overshadow the `text` property, so the `text` property can be kept as an internal value?

Comment: Changing one affects the other. If you want to compare, why can't you compare the new attributed text value to the one assigned to the label?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, assigning to `text` replaces `attributedText` with the same contents (albeit as an unstyled attributed string), and assigning to `attributedText` replaces `text` with the same contents (without any formatting information).

If you want to attach arbitrary information to an obj-c object, you should use [associated objects](http://blog.andymatuschak.org/post/173646741/your-new-friends-obj-c-associated-objects).